# DATE_FORMAT in query generate this error: Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in

Tags: php, mysql

I’ve been trying to figure out how to fix this for about two hours, except I can’t. Yesterday everything worked well despite this error but today without me touching anything it does not work anymore.
This is my code:

```
$getprod_t = $bdd->prepare("SELECT id, author, item, qte, type, 
                                DATE_FORMAT(datee, \'%d/%m/%Y - %H:%i\') AS datee 
                            FROM registre 
                            WHERE author=:author 
                            AND item=:item 
                            AND type=1");
$getprod_t->execute([ 
    'author' => $_SESSION['username'],
    'item' => 3
]);
$prod_t = $getprod_t->fetch();
echo $prod_t['qte'];
```

Today, When I remove the DATE_FORMAT it works again, except that yesterday I didn’t need to remove it, everything worked fine.

Sincerely,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no  need to escape the single quotes

```
$getprod_t = $bdd->prepare("SELECT id, author, item, qte, type, DATE_FORMAT(datee, '%d/%m/%Y - %H:%i') AS datee FROM registre WHERE author=:author AND item=:item AND type=1");
            $getprod_t->execute([ 
                'author' => $_SESSION['username'],
                'item' => 3
            ]);
            $prod_t = $getprod_t->fetch();
            echo $prod_t['qte'];
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked ! Also, I have a small problem that delays me a lot in my project, because the modal and the collapse of my second page doesn't work while those on my main page work. Both pages have the same header and I checked that all tags are closed. Here is my code if you can help me please: https://pastebin.com/Gq7pRqMu

Comment: when you remove the / everything looks good. but lease add another question, describe completely which erroryou get or what doesn't work, but remove the /